# How we can access and Fetch a data from SharePoint on-premises on mobile device Xamarin.Android?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, xamarin.android, onpremises-gateway

How we can access and Fetch a data from SharePoint on-premises on mobile device Xamarin.Android ? http://domain/sites/MobileApp/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx, this is a URL. How Can i use this in xamarin.android Code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the `SharePoint APIs`. Please check the steps in the link below. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/add-collaboration-to-your-mobile-apps-with-sharepoint/

Comment: this is for Sharepoint Online Right? I don't want Azure Register. Im using SharePoint on-premises.Can You Please Help me to solve this problem.